# Adobe Photoshop CC 2015 moving layer question

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I drag and drop one of the layer in the layer panel,then it would automatically aim this layer to the first one layer. Can't the panel just hold on there, not move? After the panel moved, I always need to fine the layers' relationship again. It annoyed me a lot.

[screencast.com/t/YNt2bh6DCjOD](http://screencast.com/t/YNt2bh6DCjOD) Take the video for example.

you can see now I want to put [ Text- Health] this layer above the [bg] layer. 
Ideally, the layer panel won't move, and see the [bg] is above [Health].Then you can see after I drop [Health], the panel automatically move [Health] layer to the in the view's top. Can't the panel just hold on there, not move?

Comment: It's just the UI trying to keep the moved layer in view within the panel.  The only way I'm aware of around this is to have the panel tall enough that all layers are visible.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to let the panel tall enough, the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[From PS feedback site:](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/auto-scrolling-on-layers-panel-when-a-layer-is-copied-deleted-or-added-to-a-folder)**

- > This was a bug introduced as a side effect of another change. We're looking into a fix. Thanks for letting us know.
- > This issue should be corrected in the Photoshop CC 2015.0.1 update which was released today. [Details here](http://blogs.adobe.com/crawlspace/2015/08/photoshop-cc-2015-0-1-update-now-available.html)".

---

This issue was also reported in the [Adobe forums.](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1899316)

Answer (score 0):

You mean when you drag a Layer from one document into another the Layer is always at the Top?
Just before you drag it to the new Document choose the Layer below where you want the New Layer to have.
Example:
Layer 6
Layer 5
Layer 4
Layer 3
Layer 2
Layer 1

You want the Layer from Document 2 between Layer 3 and 4 then you have to click on Layer 3 and then drag the new Layer into the document and will be placed at the right position.

If this is not your problem i personally need some screenshots because then i don't understand your problem :)

Comment: I record a video for you. http://screencast.com/t/YNt2bh6DCjOD 
Take the video for example, you can see now I want to put [ Text- Health] this layer above the [bg] layer. Ideally, the layer panel won't move, and see the [bg] is above [Health]. Then you can see after I drop [Health], the panel automatically move [Health] layer to the in the view's top. Can't the panel just hold on there, not move?

Comment: There's no way you can change that but actually that shouldn't that much of a problem? 
It's really easy to go up the layer panel with the mouse wheel.
Otherwise i would suggest that you change your Workspace so that the Layer Panel is stretched over one complete side.